# Increasing a progress bar for every topic click and every chapter individually

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a `ChapterViewController`, in this controller I have 3-4 chapters. If I click chapter 1 then open `topicViewController`, in this controller there are many topics, and the header section has a progress bar. If I click topic 1 then open topic `detailsViewController` and when back the progress bar increases in percentage. Every chapter has many topics and every topic controller individual progress bar.

Comment: how you want to increase the progressbar their are so many possiblities  ?

Comment: The topics are show in table view. how could i get every topic row clicked once. Every Click the progress bar increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do the progress bar aspect, I'm sure people will have opinions on its merit.

Step 1: ViewController.h: Declare A Property: 'progressView'

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *progressView;
```

Step 2: ViewController.m: Add progressView to view

```
self.progressView = [[UIView alloc]init];
self.progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 100);
[self.view addSubview:self.progressView];
```

Step 3: ViewController.m: Add the following method somewhere

```
- (void) updateProgressViewWithPercentageDone:(int)percentDone {
    CALayer * progressIndicatorLayer;
    if (self.progressView.layer.sublayers.count == 0) {
        progressIndicatorLayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
        progressIndicatorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        progressIndicatorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, self.progressView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.progressView.layer addSublayer:progressIndicatorLayer];
    }
    else {
        progressIndicatorLayer = self.progressView.layer.sublayers[0];
    }

    int targetWidth = (self.progressView.bounds.size.width / 100) * percentDone;
    progressIndicatorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, self.progressView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

Step 4: ViewController.m: Call method

```
[self updateProgressViewWithPercentageDone:50];
```

Would be 50% done, etc.

Comment: hey thanks for the solution but how can i get the number of click.
Means the progress bar increases between total topics and the increment of progress bar is count of every topic clicked once.
like this :
targetWidth = clicked-row * percentValue / total-Topic-row ;

Comment: int percentDone = numberOfChoicesAlreadyCompleted / totalAvailableChoices;

Comment: sorry i can't understand that how could i get "numberOfChoices".
The topics are show in table view. how could i get every topic row clicked once. Every Click the progress bar increase.

Comment: You're going to have to store that value somewhere and update it when the user clicks a row.